# redux unnecessarily rerenders whole component

Tags: reactjs, redux, rerender

the problem is as follows:

this is what i have in my redux duck

```
export const myInit = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
   db.ref(`/parts/`).on(
       'value',
        (snapshot) => 
(dispatch(getParts(mapObjectToArray(snapshot.val())))))
}

export const addAmount = (objecter) => (dispatch, getState) => {
let findKey = getState().partsState.parts.find(x => {
    if (x.part === objecter)
        return x.key
})
let xAmount

getState().partsState.parts.find(x => {
    if (x.part === objecter)
        return xAmount = x.amount
})
db.ref(`/parts/${findKey.key}/amount`).set(xAmount + 1)
```

}

myInit() is called once in the store so the parts are saved in the state.

I display those parts in my component in a table. In each tr there is a name of part, amount and a button to change amount of parts. Once you click the button, the amount of the given part changes. Everything seems to be working just fine unless, the amount change is called when parts are filtered with state of an input value.

When list is filtered, and amount of part is changed, the whole component rerenders. Search field is cleared and the list extends. I don't know what to do. Please tell me what am I missing.

the component:

```
class ListOfParts extends Component {
state = {
    basicSearchInput: '',
    ITEMS_PER_PAGE: 10,
    currentPage: 0,
    parts: []
}

setStateForSearch(event) {
    this.setState({basicSearchInput: event.target.value})
}


render() {
    let myArrayForState = ['actuator', 'back_plate']

    let arrayForHeadings = ['Actuator', 'Back plate'
    ]

    let parts = this.props.parts;
    const filter = parts
        .filter(part => {
                return (part.part.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.basicSearchInput.toLowerCase()))
                    || (part.group.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.basicSearchInput.toLowerCase()))
            }
        )

    const numberOfParts = filter && filter.length

    return (
        <div>
           <TextField
               type={"search"}
               value={this.state.basicSearchInput}
                onChange={event => this.setStateForSearch(event)}
           />
           <RaisedButton
                onClick={this.handleOpen}
           >
           add
           </RaisedButton>

            <Row>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    {filter && filter.length ?
                        filter.filter((el, i) => {
                            return (i >= this.state.ITEMS_PER_PAGE * this.state.currentPage
                                &&
                                i < this.state.ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (this.state.currentPage + 1))
                        }).map((partInStateArray, index) =>
                             <tr id={`${partInStateArray.part}`}
                                 key={`${partInStateArray.part}${this.props.index}`}>
                                 <td>{this.arrayForHeadings[this.myArrayForState.indexOf(partInStateArray.group)]} {partInStateArray.part}</td>
                                 <td>{partInStateArray.amount}</td>
                                 <td>
                                     <button onClick={this.add}>+</button>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>)
                        )
                        : 'loading'
                    }
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </Row>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Pagination
                    total={Math.ceil(numberOfParts / this.state.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)}
                    current={this.state.currentPage + 1}
                    display={10}
                    onChange={newPage => this.setState({currentPage: newPage - 1})}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
parts: state.partsState.parts,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
addAmount: (objectToAdd) => dispatch(addAmount(objectToAdd)),
})

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(ListOfParts)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem. "Re-rendering" is how React updates the screen. If you call `setState()`, it will re-render, so typing in the search box will cause a re-render (which is what you want, so you can filter and change what's shown). Can you clarify what's "wrong" or broken here?

Comment: I would like the list to be constantly filtered when amount changes. Shouldn't it be like only the row that is changed re-renders? :P I can see that redux sees the change only in this part, so why all the rows rerender?

Comment: initial state should be placed in constructor - change in props from redux should force render (it's normal) but shouldn't affect state